# How to improve code and avoid duplications?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have the following code that describes models and emitters:

```
export class Findbyobjectidlatest {
  onChanged = new EventEmitter<Ifindbyobjectidlatest>();
  model = <Ifindbyobjectidlatest>{ pagesize: 10 };
  emit() {
    this.onChanged.emit(this.model);
  }
}

export class Findbycadnum {
  onChanged = new EventEmitter<Ifindbycadnum>();
  model = <Ifindbycadnum>{ pagesize: 10 };
  emit() {
    this.onChanged.emit(this.model);
  }
}

export class Findbycadastnumber {
  onChanged = new EventEmitter<Ifindbycadastnumber>();
  model = <Ifindbycadastnumber>{ pagesize: 10 };
  emit() {
    this.onChanged.emit(this.model);
  }
}
```

How can I improve this, because classes are the similar.

Also I have repository class:

```
class RepositoryModel {
   findbyobjectidlatest = new Findbyobjectidlatest();
   findbycadnum = new Findbycadnum();
   findbycadastnumber = new Findbycadastnumber();
}
```

Then I use it:

const repositoryModel = new RepositoryModel();

```
repositoryModel.findbyobjectidlatest.onChanged().pipe().subscribe();
```

And etc.

Comment: I have amended my question

Comment: Did you try using single class with <any>?

Comment: If this is code you've written yourself, and you want a review of all aspects of the code, you should consider visiting the help center at [codereview.se] to see if the question is on topic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a base class with a generic type:

```
class BaseModelEmitter<T extends {pagesize: number}> {
  onChanged = new EventEmitter<T>();
  model = <T>{ pagesize: 10 };
  emit() {
    this.onChanged.emit(this.model);
  }
}
```

then just have your classes extend....

```
export class Findbycadnum extends BaseModelEmitter<Ifindbycadnum> { }
```

any class you use to implement this base MUST implement that pagesize interface.

or just use it directly and skip the extension if you wish (but extension allows customization):

```
findbyobjectidlatest = new BaseModelEmitter<Ifindbycadnum>();
```